# Delete the particular file if file size more then 20MB and specified filename

Tags: vbscript

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

sDirectoryPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\z\"

Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sDirectoryPath)
Set oFileCollection = oFolder.Files

If oFile.Size > 20000000 And ofile.Filename = "nor.dotm Then
  oFile.Delete(True)
End If
```

Throwing error please suggest

Comment: oFile is never declare or assigned to anything. If you want to do this for a specific file use GetFile not GetFolder. There is a missing quote around nor.dotm.

Comment: Can you help me out

Comment: File name or .Dotm OK with both

Comment: Please always include the actual error message when asking a question about code that raises an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, you want to delete all files in the folder by looping, which are greater than 20MB in size.

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

sDirectoryPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\z\"

set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sDirectoryPath)

set oFileCollection = oFolder.Files

For Each ofile in oFileCollection 


 If oFile.Size > 20000000 and ofile.name ="nor.dotm" Then

    oFile.Delete(True)

 End If

Next
```

If you want to delete a particular file only,

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

```
sDirectoryPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\z\"
FileName = "MyFile.Txt"

'set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sDirectoryPath)

set ofile = oFSO.GetFile(sDirectoryPath & FileName)      


If oFile.Size > 20000000 and ofile.name ="nor.dotm" Then

   oFile.Delete(True)

End If
```

Comment: If size 20mb and extension or file name match then delete the file ,write log particular file deleted in .Log file

Answer (score 0):

You have several mistakes in the code you posted, some of which Alex K. already [pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055945/delete-the-particular-file-if-file-size-more-then-20mb-and-specified-file-name#comment77085125_45055945).

- There's a double quote missing after your reference filename.
- No file object is ever assigned to the variable `oFile`.
- You enumerate the files in the directory, but you never iterate over the collection.
- The property holding the name of a file object is [`Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zawxett8.aspx), not `Filename`.

If you just want to check if a particular file in a given folder exceeds a given size you should use `GetFile` instead of iterating over all files in the folder, and simply check the file's size:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

dir = "C:\Users\Desktop\z"

Set f = fso.GetFile(fso.BuildPath(dir, "nor.dotm"))

If f.Size > 20000000 Then
  f.Delete True
End If
```

If you want to check files with a particular extension, you need to actually iterate over the files in the folder:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

dir = "C:\Users\Desktop\z"

For Each f In fso.GetFolder(dir).Files
  If f.Size > 20000000 And fso.GetExtensionName(f) = "dotm" Then
    f.Delete True
  End If
Next
```